# Notify when WinUI binding updating is finished

Tags: xaml, winui-3

Say I have this TabView:

```
<TabView   TabItemsSource="{x:Bind Tabs,Mode=OneWay}" TabItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template_Tab}" >
```

When (say) my tabs need to be updated, I post the notification and my callback is called.
Now, when do I know that the loading is finished?

For example, I want to know when I can loop the items

```
    auto nav = Content().as<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView>();
    auto tab = nav.FindName(L"Tab_Tabs").as<TabView>();
    for (auto ti : tab.TabItems())
    {
        auto itx = ti.as<Item>();
        auto cont = tab.ContainerFromItem(ti).as<TabViewItem>();
    }
```

This returns null until the Tab control is ready. How do I know when this occurs?

Comment: There's no such event (there's FrameworkElement.LayoutUpdated, FrameworkElement.Loaded, FrameworkElement.SizeChanged), but it's usually not needed once you think "xaml + databinding", ie: it depends what you really want to do with the TabViewItem, maybe you can do it differently.